# Windows firewall disable without domain

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

how to globaly disable Windows firewall on all client's PC from Windows Server 2012 R2 without domain? It is possible?

Thank you 
Dyno

Comment: Sure;  Do it on a single machine with it disabled, Sysprep it, then create a deployable image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows 7+, and that you have the administrator credentials for the machines you want to target, create a batch file that runs `Netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off`, and then run it on each client PC using something like [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).